# android facebook sdk, sharing -- how to detect succcess?

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0, android-simple-facebook

Following the tutorial on [Facebook Android SDK Official Site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/), in the place where I set the `uiHelper .onActivityResult`, I realised that.. whether I post something to the web or not (even if I simply press the back button directly), "onSuccess" would be always called.

I also discovered this [Android Simple Facebook](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) library, which simplify the process a lot. However, following the tutorial, I found that no matter I succeeded with posting or not.. I ended up having "onFail" called.

I wonder what should I do now to verify if user has successfully posted the result

Update: I realised a similar question with solution is [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746067/using-share-dialog-in-android-facebook-sdk-how-to-know-is-user-actually-shared)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using share dialog in Android Facebook SDK. How to know is user actually shared or cancelled sharing activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746067/using-share-dialog-in-android-facebook-sdk-how-to-know-is-user-actually-shared)

Comment: What is the `reason` value do you get in `onFail()`?

Comment: @sromku Wow.. you seems to be the author of <Android Simple Facebook> library~~ I want thank you for creating such an easy to use API :) The reason I got for the onFail(): Failed with reason: Canceled by user

Comment: @sromku Hopefully you don't mind me asking a side question here.. if I want to use Facebook SDK with Fragment.. Is there anything special I should take care of..? It seems that everything there's no result being returned, following the Facebook's official SDK.

Comment: thanks :) and, please ask any question, this is the place :) see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Regarding [android-simple-facebook](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook):

Few things you need to double check in your code as described [**here**](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook#usage):

- `onResume()`
- `onActivityResult()`
- Check that you [configured permissions](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook#configuration) (at least one).

Regarding `Fragments` there is no special stuff you should take care for. [Please check this sample](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/blob/master/Simple%20Facebook%20Sample/src/com/sromku/simple/fb/example/friends/FriendsListFragment.java).

You can try the sample app and see that it works for you. This is the sample app on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sromku.simple.fb.example) and this is the [source](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/tree/master/Simple%20Facebook%20Sample). The sample app includes `Fragment`.

Let me know if it worked for you :)